# convert data from database into one map

Tags: dictionary, parsing, go

The problem is - I don't want to create a struct for every database (too much code if I describe all structures for all XMLs, I have more than 200 DBs). So I need smth what can be used for any of them

The data for one of my DB's looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
Id  |      Path                          |Value
-----------------------------------------------
1   | SalesPlan/SalesPlanData/Year       | 2021
2   | SalesPlan/SalesPlanData/Month      | July
3   | SalesPlan/SalesPlanPerson/id       | 123
....
1700| SalesPlan/SalesPlarSpot/Spots/City | NY
```

I tried many ways but in the end, I can't create a flexible map-structure, which can be correctly updated  after each DB row
The next code allows me to store all final tags, but I want to move up on the tree and update the hole structure

```
type ParentTag struct {
    Key   string
    Value []InnerTag
}

type InnerTag struct {
    Key   string
    Value string
}

func (s *ParentTag) Add(i InnerTag) {
    s.Value = append(s.Value, i)
    log.Printf("New X=%d", s.Value)
}

func main() {
    //xmlMap := Tag{}
    parentTagsStorage := []ParentTag{}

    house_1 := []string{"mydoc", "Country", "City", "Street", "House", "14"}
    house_2 := []string{"mydoc", "Country", "City", "Street", "House", "15"}
    street_1 := []string{"mydoc", "Country", "City", "Street", "Maddison"}
    city_1 := []string{"mydoc", "Country", "City", "NY"}

    allData := make([][]string, 0)
    allData = append(allData, house_1)
    allData = append(allData, house_2)
    allData = append(allData, street_1)
    allData = append(allData, city_1)


    for _, row := range allData {
        // the latest 2 elements present xml-tag and all previous ones are parents tags
        // <Street>
        //    <House>1</House>
        // </Street>
        innerTag := InnerTag{
            Key:   row[len(row)-2],
            Value: row[len(row)-1],
        }
        ifParentTagExist := false

        for i, pTag := range parentTagsStorage {
            if pTag.Key == row[len(row)-3] {
                pTag.Add(innerTag)
                parentTagsStorage[i] = pTag
                ifParentTagExist = true
            }
        }
        if !ifParentTagExist {
            parentTag := ParentTag{
                Key:   row[len(row)-3],
                Value: []InnerTag{innerTag},
            }
            parentTagsStorage = append(parentTagsStorage, parentTag)
        }
    }
}
```

I will be very pleased for any ideas

Comment: Why would you convert to JSON, if your goal is XML?

Comment: I really don't know how to do it better. I can use marshal with JSON, not sure I can do it with a map directly

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you have JSON, then there's nothing to marshal. If you have JSON, you have to first _unmarshal_, before you can then marshal to XML.

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of the XML document you're after — matching the input data you've provided at the beginning of your question?

Comment: @Flimzy, I could guess that many front-end developers maintain quite a vague idea about the distinction between JS objects, which behave as maps, and JSON. So I think this bit can just be dropped from the question's title.

Comment: Still, can we see the sample of a final XML document you'd like to have for the sample of the input data? I mean, I, for one, have difficulty with interpreting what you're after. Your description looks like an honest attempt to describe that but it's part code and part words, and I fail to sensibly connect them together.

Comment: @kostix, deleted, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here we go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type pathVal struct {
    path string
    val  interface{}
}

func encode(dst io.Writer, src []pathVal) error {
    enc := xml.NewEncoder(dst)
    enc.Indent("", "\t") // for a prettier look

    tree := makeTree(src)

    err := encodeTree(enc, tree)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return enc.Flush()
}

func encodeTree(enc *xml.Encoder, tree tree) error {
    for key, node := range tree {
        err := enc.EncodeToken(xml.StartElement{
            Name: xml.Name{
                Local: key,
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if node.SubTree != nil {
            err = encodeTree(enc, node.SubTree)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        if node.Value != nil {
            err = encodeValue(enc, node.Value)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }

        err = enc.EncodeToken(xml.EndElement{
            Name: xml.Name{
                Local: key,
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func encodeValue(enc *xml.Encoder, val interface{}) error {
    return enc.EncodeToken(xml.CharData(fmt.Sprintf("%v", val)))
}

type tree map[string]*treeNode

type treeNode struct {
    SubTree tree
    Value   interface{}
}

func makeTree(src []pathVal) tree {
    root := make(tree)

    for _, elem := range src {
        comps := strings.Split(elem.path, "/")
        comps, last := comps[:len(comps)-1], comps[len(comps)-1]

        subTree := root
        for _, comp := range comps {
            node, exists := subTree[comp]
            if !exists {
                newTree := make(tree)
                subTree[comp] = &treeNode{
                    SubTree: newTree,
                }
                subTree = newTree
                continue
            }
            if node.SubTree == nil {
                node.SubTree = make(tree)
            }
            subTree = node.SubTree
        }

        if node, exists := subTree[last]; exists {
            node.Value = elem.val
        } else {
            subTree[last] = &treeNode{
                Value: elem.val,
            }
        }
    }

    return root
}

// "Table 1"
var data1 = []pathVal{
    pathVal{
        path: "SalesPlan/SalesPlanData/Year",
        val:  2021,
    },
    pathVal{
        path: "SalesPlan/SalesPlanData/Month",
        val:  "July",
    },
    pathVal{
        path: "SalesPlan/SalesPlanData/id",
        val:  123,
    },
    pathVal{
        path: "SalesPlan/SalesPlanSpot/Spots/City",
        val:  "NY",
    },
}

// "Table 2"
var data2 = []pathVal{
    pathVal{
        path: "mydoc/Country/City/Street/House",
        val:  14,
    },
    pathVal{
        path: "mydoc/Country/City/Street/House",
        val:  15,
    },
    pathVal{
        path: "mydoc/Country/City/Street",
        val:  "Maddison",
    },
    pathVal{
        path: "mydoc/Country/City",
        val:  "NY",
    },
}

func main() {
    out, _ := json.MarshalIndent(makeTree(data1), "", "\t")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
    fmt.Println(encode(os.Stdout, data1))

    out, _ = json.MarshalIndent(makeTree(data2), "", "\t")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
    fmt.Println(encode(os.Stdout, data2))
}
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tzJlG5OKvGQ).)

On the sample data (both "tables" embedded into the example as `data1` and `data2`) we get

```xml
<SalesPlan>
    <SalesPlanData>
        <id>123</id>
        <Year>2021</Year>
        <Month>July</Month>
    </SalesPlanData>
    <SalesPlanSpot>
        <Spots>
            <City>NY</City>
        </Spots>
    </SalesPlanSpot>
</SalesPlan>
```

and

```xml
<mydoc>
    <Country>
        <City>
            <Street>
                <House>15</House>Maddison
            </Street>NY
        </City>
    </Country>
</mydoc>
```

respectively.

Note those "weirdly-looking" cases of "Maddison" placed inside the `<Street>` element and "NY" placed inside the `<City>` element;
also note the absense of the `<House>14</House>`.
I don't know how exactly to deal with these two issues (if they are issues) as your question does not explicitly state any preference regarding handling of them.

I would say dealing with multiple leaf elements is reasonably easy — just make sure to not overwrite `Value` in `makeTree`, but rather provide for gathering multiple values (possibly collected in a slice) and account for that in `encodeTree`.
What to do with the case of a would-be XML element which should contain both a "plain" value and a nested element is really an open question: what I've shown is 100% standards-compliant XML but the end result may *feel* unnatural for what one usually expects to see in a human-readable XML document.

Still, let me leave these as an exercise for the reader.

---

Note that the solution only uses the `encoding/json` package to "dump" the tree created by `makeTree` from the input data; it's not needed for the algorythm to work.

Comment: I have no words to express all my thankfulness! This is awesome!

Comment: "What to do with the case of a would-be XML element which should contain both a "plain" value and a nested element" - you are absolutely right - this is a bad(wrong) example from my side (my fault, sorry)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please take time to really understand the implemented idea (building a tree from reusable "nodes" where on each tree "level" there's a map which maps "path components" to nodes, each of which may contain a leaf element and/or a subtree; then encoding the resulting tree as XML by using "token encoder"). I mean, don't just blindly copy the solution; _the approach_ should sink in in order to be useful. Cheers!